# How to load a model once and store it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, model, three.js, load

I have a problem where i load a model like that:

```
var Beech;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "./models/trees/Beech/Beech.json", function( geometry, materials ) {
Beech = addMorphTree(geometry,materials,0.5); });
```

and using it like this :

```
function addMorphTree(geometry,material,scale){
            mat=new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( material );
            mat.side=THREE.DoubleSide;
            Tree = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,mat);
            Tree.scale.set(scale,scale,scale);
            //Tree.position.set(x,y,z);
            Tree.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;

            //scene.add( Tree );
        return Tree;}
```

My question is how can i use this variable to create copies of the model instead of loading it every time? When i try to use

```
scene.add(Beech);
```

outside the  loader the  model doesn't show up. I have seen other similar questions but all the answers where to use the scene.add inside the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason that the model does not show up in the scene when you try to add it outside of the loader, is because the loading is done asynchronous. This means, that while the loader is loading, the rest of the code will run. So if you try to add "Beech" to the scene directly after the loading function, it will not have finished loaded yet.

```
var Beech;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "./models/trees/Beech/Beech.json", function( geometry, materials ) {
Beech = addMorphTree(geometry,materials,0.5); });
scene.add(Beech);  // <-- this will run before the function above is finished,
                   //thereby adding a undefined variable to the scene.
```

If you want more than one instance of the variable, maybe you can try the clone() function. Since Beech is a Mesh object, and Mesh inherits from Object3D, it can also use Object3D member functions.

```
var Beech;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "./models/trees/Beech/Beech.json", function( geometry, materials ) {
Beech = addMorphTree(geometry,materials,0.5); 
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  scene.add(Beech.clone()) //creates 5 trees
}
});
```

Comment: Very useful thank you.! :) but i guess the clone() function was what i was missing.